# Secure HttpWebRequest so I can send credentials possible?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following code which connects to my php server and retrieves data from it. The only thing is, I need to send the username and password securely from this webrequest to the PHP server. Looking at the docs for the webrequest class, there is a credentials property as well as a preauthenticate property. I'm assuming these are for the network credentials (all my users are in AD).

Is it possible to secure this post request with credentials or is this just a bad idea? I've also found SetBasicAuthHeader - I'll read up on this and see if it might help. All traffic will be on SSL from ASPX site to the PHP site

```
    // variables to store parameter values
    string url = "https://myphpserver.php";

    // creates the post data for the POST request
    string postData = "Username=" + username + "&Password=" + "&UID=" + UniqueRecID;

    // create the POST request
    HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    webRequest.Method = "POST";
    webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    webRequest.ContentLength = postData.Length;

    // POST the data
    using (StreamWriter requestWriter2 = new StreamWriter(webRequest.GetRequestStream()))
    {
        requestWriter2.Write(postData);
    }

    //  This actually does the request and gets the response back
    HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();

    string responseData = string.Empty;

    using (StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(webRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()))
    {
        // dumps the HTML from the response into a string variable
        responseData = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SetBasicAuthHeader is for [HTTP Basic Access Authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) so won't help here as you're handling authentication at application level. Really, this is no more insecure than just going to the page in a browser. I see you're using SSL so your request will be encrypted anyway and you have nothing to worry about.

If you're concerned for some other reason (although I can't think why), it sounds like you have control over the PHP end so you could just encrypt the password and add an extra POST parameter so the server knows to decrypt it.

Answer (score 0):

When using HTTPS your data is safe in the message and transport scope. It means no one can decode it or sniff the packets. I suggest you read this article [HTTPS Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Secure)